# Importar datos de XLS a SQL problema con el tipo de datos

Tags: sql, xls

Hola soy nuevo en la programación, tengo problemas para importar datos desde excel a SQL, esta vez una de las columnas del archivo xls que tiene contenido alfanumérico, relacionado a modelos de autos puntualmente.
Tras algunas pruebas me di cuenta que SQL toma la primer celda de la columna y acorde al tipo de dato de esa celda asigna al resto de la columna, es decir: si el primer dato de la celda es "500" va a leer todas las celdas como numéricas y va a pasar nulas aquellas celdas que tengan texto y viceversa, si la celda arranca con "a500" pasa nulas las celdas que tengan números.

Explicado de otra forma si hablamos de datos fuentes y datos recibidos en relación a los datos recibidos puedo elegir el mapping, es decir donde van a "aterrizar" esos datos fuentes, en que tabla que columna de excel para que columna de tabla en SQL.
El problema es que SQL al leer el tipo de datos de los datos fuentes pareciera que anula las celdas numericas o de texto de la columna tomada dependiendo el tipo de datos de la primer celda de excel.

Entonces la pregunta es cuestión es:
¿Como podría hacer para transportar todos los datos de esa columna sin nulos? ¿Hay alguna forma de elegir como tiene que leer los datos SQL? [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido F. Gabriel Sosa Rozzi a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Nunca importé directamente de un Excel, pero.. ¿No hay forma de especificar el tipo de dato de cada columna? una opción, podrías ser agregar una fila dummy con caracteres, otra podría ser "encerrar" cada dato no numérico con comillas.

Comment: Gracias por responder patricio.
1) Si existe alguna forma de especificar como tiene que leer SQL los datos fuentes desconozco, pero quizás sería la pregunta clave a este tema.

2) Desconozco lo que es una fila dummy, por lo que no puedo opinar. 

3)Estaría bueno crear (o saber crear) una suerte de función para intecerptar el lector de SQL y encerrar cada dato numérico en comillas para que SQL los adapte a texto, la alternativa sería ir fila por fila en excel y ponerle comillas a los datos numéricos.

Comment: Ahí lo miré, fijate que tenés un botón "edit mappings", ahí te abre una vista con la definición de la tabla que va a crear, eventualmente intentá modificar el tipo de datos de las columnas donde tenés problemas.

Comment: Quizá me esté explicando mal, cito esta parte que redacte en la explicación del tema y me explico:
..." si el primer dato de la celda es "500" va a leer todas las celdas como numéricas y va a pasar nulas aquellas celdas que tengan texto y viceversa, si la celda arranca con "a500" pasa nulas las celdas que tengan números."...
Probablemente tenga algún tipo de bug, pero fijate en la imagen que adjunte junto con el tema que hay una columna "Nombre" que tiene campos vacíos, esos campos, que son celdas en excel, en excel tienen datos de tipo texto pero SQL no los lee

Comment: Mi comentario apuntaba a que eventualmente (no lo sé) lo que define la conversión es la tabla que SQL Server va a crear. Si Nombre se define automáticamente como columna `INT`, ¿qué pasa si editas la definicón y la colocas como varchar?

Comment: Acabo de probarlo con un SQL management 18.5 y no logro reproducir el comportamiento que dices, al menos con un excel simple que mezcla caracteres con números en la misma columna, la importación parece hacerla bien. Habría que ver como es tu archivo.

Comment: He subido el archivo XLS al google drive por si queres revisarlo

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rb8iiqE9ez2SwXIRORiz0nXhnyjxxwoC?usp=sharing

por otro lado mi versión de SQL
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      14.0.17289.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools      14.0.1016.283
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      10.0.18362.1
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer      9.11.18362.0
Microsoft .NET Framework      4.0.30319.42000
Operating System      6.3.18362

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que el comportamiento de la importación es bastante particular, efectivamente define la columna en función de la primer fila. Una posibilidad podría haber sido agregar una primer fila dummy para forzar la evaluación de la columna a una cadena, algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero, lo que ocurre en estos casos, es que importa, correctamente las cadenas pero ignora los números, porj: el `500` de la tercer fila no lo transforma en cadena, lo ignora.

Modificar la definición de las columnas de la tabla tampoco sirve. La solución que encontré, pasa por "decirle" al Excel que un determinado número lo considere un texto, el metódo clásico es agregar una comilla simple delante del número:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ahora sí:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias patricio! Efectivamente la solución es ponerle adelante a cada celda las comillas simples. Ahora me fijo si encuentro alguna manera de generar una función para esa columna que detecte cuando la fila sea numérica y si es numérica reemplace lo que hay por el mismo contenido sumado a un " ' ", ya que son bastantes registros, si encuentro como comparto el método por acá